# npm install error - setting dev env

Tags: npm-install, nvm

trying set up dev env for kibana 
i cloned kibana ; cd kibana 
and run npm install 
 getting the following error :

```
 C:\kibana>npm install
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
    Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "elasticsearch"
19 error node v6.10.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error kibana@6.0.0-alpha2 elasticsearch: `grunt esvm:dev:keepalive`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the kibana@6.0.0-alpha2 elasticsearch script 'grunt esvm:dev:keepalive'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the kibana package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     grunt esvm:dev:keepalive
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs kibana
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls kibana
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Try upgrade you're node js

Comment: i did to the latest version , not working